Dual Boot Win10 / Linux: Migrate from BIOS to EFI
How do I proceed to migrate a dual-boot system (Linux / Win10) from Legacy/BIOS to EFI without reinstalling everything?
My situation: Dual-Boot (Linux Mint / Windows 10) system with three two SSDs and one HDD, MBR-based, grub2 as boot manager.
I've tried the steps described here: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GRUB_2_von_BIOS_nach_EFI_umstellen/ (in German, sorry...) which failed - not sure why. shim_lock was missing after finishing the procedure, no Ubuntu or Linux mint entry in efibootmgr -v output. Additionally, there's no step converting the MBR to GPT using gdisk. I've reverted the result by re-installing grub-pc using a live system.
I wonder if I first have to migrate Win10 from MBR to GPT? Or can I migrate Windows afterwards? I assume I can't directly use MBR2GPT provided by Microsoft, because there are ext4-Partitions on the same disk where Win10 resides?

Why do you want to convert from BIOS to EFI?

@DavidAnderson: Without EFI no Win11, and without Win11 no more updates for Windows at some point in 2025.

Windows 11 does BIOS boot. However, you cannot upgrade a BIOS booting Windows 10 to Windows 11. You would have to do a clean install of a BIOS booting Windows 11. A clean install of Windows 11 will be free, as long as your current Windows 10 has been activated. In other words, you will be able to activate Windows 11 without having to purchase a license. I have a 2007 iMac and 2011 iMac running a BIOS booting Windows 11.

It's probably worth considering investing in another SSD (cost of time vs the cost of the drive) **.
If you go that path, I would suggest partitioning the new drive as GPT and then migrating your linux system to EFI it should be possible to boot off a UEFI media and install a boot loader into the EFI partition - the rest of linux shouldn't care about the drive partitioning mechanism - Linux doesn't care if it boots off one drive and the majority of it's files are on a different drive.
Once thats done migrate all your ext4 partitions from the windows drive to the new drive (just copy them and update the mount point). You can then remove the ext4 partitions from the Windows drive, so that drive only has Windows on it.
Optionally: Remove everything except the Windows drive from the machine (your call but I have limited trust for Windows installers - I have been burnt too many times).
Go through the standard Windows conversion (to GPT) and upgrade to Windows 11 process - you only have Windows on the drive so the installer should (theoretically) be able to handle it.
Put the other drives back in the box, in your bios set the EFI boot drive to linux and update your linux boot loader to chain load the windows drive - Optionally you can use your Bios to switch which (EFI) drive you are booting off, but it's a pain to have to go into Bios to switch every time.
** - I see you already have 3 drives - if you have the budget you might consider purchasing a larger drive and consolidating down to two drives (one for linux and one for windows).
Alternatively, if you have another smaller drive kicking around - enough to create the EFI and get the Ext4 partitions off the windows drive you may not have to purchase anything.
